# EWS Managed API Error - An object within a change description must contain one and only one property to modify

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, office365api

Any ideas why exchange keeps throwing this error?

I'm using Microsoft Exchange Managed API 2.0, from C#.
The sample request and responses are intercepted using Fiddler

I'll post a request and response sample.
I even tried to remove all properties and leave just a simple one, and still same error.
It doesn't seem to be a collections related issue

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013_SP1" />
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <m:UpdateItem MessageDisposition="SaveOnly" ConflictResolution="AlwaysOverwrite">
      <m:ItemChanges>
        <t:ItemChange>
          <t:ItemId Id="AAMkADgwNWY5NDQ3LWRkMTQtNGQyZS04ODMxLTQzMDQ1NWU5NTI2OABGAAAAAADzrqMpUzgAQoRJwq9Jq9ArBwDjC+q0IBppSKdYNLEIzckAAADAlx38AADjC+q0IBppSKdYNLEIzckAAADAly/BAAA=" ChangeKey="EQAAABYAAADjC+q0IBppSKdYNLEIzckAAADAis/g" />
          <t:Updates>
            <t:SetItemField>
              <t:FieldURI FieldURI="contacts:GivenName" />
              <t:Contact>
                <t:GivenName>Mickeyaabsbbcdsf</t:GivenName>
              </t:Contact>
            </t:SetItemField>
            <t:SetItemField>
              <t:FieldURI FieldURI="contacts:FileAs" />
              <t:Contact />
            </t:SetItemField>
            <t:DeleteItemField>
              <t:FieldURI FieldURI="contacts:FileAs" />
            </t:DeleteItemField>
          </t:Updates>
        </t:ItemChange>
      </m:ItemChanges>
    </m:UpdateItem>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <h:ServerVersionInfo xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" MajorVersion="15" MinorVersion="20" MajorBuildNumber="2241" MinorBuildNumber="12" Version="V2018_01_08"/>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <m:UpdateItemResponse xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
      <m:ResponseMessages>
        <m:UpdateItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Error">
          <m:MessageText>An object within a change description must contain one and only one property to modify.</m:MessageText>
          <m:ResponseCode>ErrorIncorrectUpdatePropertyCount</m:ResponseCode>
          <m:DescriptiveLinkKey>0</m:DescriptiveLinkKey>
          <m:MessageXml>
            <t:Value Name="PropertyCount">0</t:Value>
            <t:Value Name="PropertyInfo"/>
          </m:MessageXml>
          <m:Items/>
        </m:UpdateItemResponseMessage>
      </m:ResponseMessages>
    </m:UpdateItemResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem is, I am performing 2 operations on the "FileAs" field.
At some point in the code I assigned a value to it, use that value somewhere else in the flow, and then making it null, like it was.

This, in turns, triggers a state change in the object that holds the property.
The contact objects sees that I did an assignment, and then a null, which equals deleting the value.

This double state change is confusing for exchange, because it doesn't know which of the 2 state changes is the correct one that should be persisted in Exchange, therefore, triggering that error.

So all in all, **avoid doing this in the code!**

```
contact.FileAs = "SomeValue"
........
contact.FileAs = null;
```

You can also see the confusing effect it has on the request xml (it does a set item field, with no value, and then a delete item field)

```
<t:SetItemField>
  <t:FieldURI FieldURI="contacts:FileAs" />
  <t:Contact />
</t:SetItemField>
<t:DeleteItemField>
  <t:FieldURI FieldURI="contacts:FileAs" />
</t:DeleteItemField>
```